# struggling with an ASP.NET MVC5 routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

So, I have an MVC5 site that uses the default routing template {controller}/{action}/{id} and this works fine. Most everything in the site requires a login (i.e. [Authorize] attribute is used almost everywhere), and this works fine.

Well, now I have a need to allow anonymous access to select pages when a certain kind of link pattern is used: App/{token}/{action}. The {token} is a random string associated with something in my database. I can issue and deactivate these tokens at will.

I got this new App/{token}/{action} routing working by implementing a custom `RouteBase` that parses the incoming URL for these tokens, and, crucially, adds the the token value to the RouteData.DataTokens so that my `App` controller can make use of it without needing an explicit action argument for it. So, I added this new route to the route table *ahead* of the default routing like this:

```
// new route here
routes.Add("AppToken", new AnonAppAccessRoute());           

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here is the problem/question: adding this now route has now made my default route stop working -- everything is now going through `AnonAppAccessRoute` which of course is meant to work only for a few things. I don't understand how to make my `AnonAppAccessRoute` apply only to URLs with a certain pattern. The `MapRoute` method accepts a URL pattern, but `Add`ing a route doesn't seem to let you put a filter on it. What am I missing? I've looked around quite a bit at various blogs and documentation about routing, but I've not found good info about using the DataTokens collection (which I feel is important to my approach), and I'm not seeing a good explanation of the difference between `Add`ing a route explicitly vs calling `MapRoute`.

Here's the code of my custom `RouteBase`:

```
public class AnonAppAccessRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData result = null;

        string[] pathElements = httpContext.Request.Path.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (pathElements.Length > 0)
        {
            string token = TryGetArrayElement(pathElements, 1);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                result.DataTokens.Add("appToken", token);
                result.Values.Add("controller", "App");
                result.Values.Add("action", TryGetArrayElement(pathElements, 2, "Index"));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private string TryGetArrayElement(string[] array, int index, string defaultValue = null)
    {
        try
        {
            return array[index];
        }
        catch
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by dropping the custom `RouteBase` and instead used this `MapRoute` call like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AppAnon",
    url: "App/{token}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
);
```

Then, in my `App` controller, I did this in the `Initialize` override:

```
protected AppToken _appToken = null;

protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    string token = requestContext.RouteData.Values["token"]?.ToString();
    _appToken = Db.FindWhere<AppToken>("[Token]=@token", new { token });
    if (!_appToken?.IsActive ?? false) throw new Exception("The token is not found or inactive.");
}
```

This way, my "token" is available to all controller actions via the `_appToken` variable, and already validated. I did not need to use `RouteData.DataTokens`. Note that my `Db.FindWhere` statement is ORM-specific and not really related to the question -- it's just how I look up a database record.